# flow adding Opportunity getting Contract ID: id value of incorrect type

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow were I look up the contact id and save it in a var.(see below)

> RECORD QUERY: Find_Contact
>   Find one Contact record where:
>   AccountId Equals {!varAccountId} (0012a00000ODWjeAAH)
>   FirstName Equals {!svar_Lead.FirstName} (Sue)
>   LastName Equals {!svar_Lead.LastName} (Super)
>   Result
>   Successfully found record.
>   {!varContactId} = 0032a00000VFQsWAAX

After that the flow assign it to a Opportunity sobject variable and then assigns it to a sobject variable collection. In the process of doing a fast create of the Opportunity I see the following:

> FAST CREATE: Create_Opportunities
>   Create Opportunity records using the values that are stored in >{!scvarNewOpportunity}.
>   Variable Values
>   [AccountId=0012a00000ODWjeAAH,Amount=60000.0,CloseDate=11/30/2018 5:00 >PM,Customer_Email__c=ssuper@test.com,LeadSource=Trade Show,Name=Sue Super - >Sun,StageName=New,Customer_Phone__c=9292305525,DBA_Name__c=null,Gross_Annual_In>come__c=null,Household_Gross_Annual_Income__c=null,Lease_Monthly__c=null,Number>_Of_Employees__c=null,Own_Business__c=No,Retirement__c=No,Years_In_College__c=n>ull,Credit_Score__c=null,First_Name__c=Sue,Last_Name__c=Super,Pre_Qualify__c=cs>1,Source_Code__c=Self Direct-mr,ContractId=0032a00000VFQsWAAX]
>   Result
>   Failed to create records.

with the following Error:

> Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: >FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Contract ID: id value of incorrect type: >0032a00000VFQsWAAX. You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API >Developer Guide.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to put a *Contact* ID in to a *Contract* ID. Those are two different types of records. You're probably going to want to create an Opportunity Contact Role instead.